# got trouble in my first AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

hey everyone i m trying to send request with AJAX by button trigger and got the response html file in span area , and i don t know where is the problem here i try something but without result check my code :

//ajax.php

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajax() {
            var xmlhttp;

            //check the xml object comptbl
            if (window.xmlHttpRequest) 
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             else 
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
            //check the request and make the response 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 & xmlhttp.status == 200) 

                    document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "info.html", true);
            xmlhttp.send();


        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="ajax">

    <!--response area -->
</span>

<button type="button" onclick="ajax()">make the request</button>


</body>


</html>
```

//info.html

```
   <html>

    <head>
        <title>the response file</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        h1,h3 {
            color: green;
     font-family : 'ALGERIAN';

        }



    </style>

    <body>

        <h1>WELCOME IM THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVEUR</h1>
        <h3>WITHOUT RELOAD THE WHOLE PAGE</h3>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser inspect element console? Do you have PHP errors enabled? Does the inspect element network tab show any php errors for the ajax request?

Comment: Your `info.html` should not contain `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

Comment: ...did you check what you get for `xmlhttp.responseText` or if you even ever hit the status 200

Comment: `&` should actually be `&&` - but will work also Bitwise in this case.

Comment: @Goose no i didn't get any EROR,when i click on the button there is no thing happen on the page(i usually get error in my php codes so error is enabled lol ) no tab error

Comment: @Jeff i got it thanks for your attention :)

Comment: @MedoFsociety heads up in case you don't know, your network tab in your browsers inspect element will show you the response from the server, including any PHP errors.

Answer (score 1):

Change your //info.html to this

```
<style>
    h1,h3 {
        color: green;
 font-family : 'ALGERIAN';
    }
</style>


    <h1>WELCOME IM THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVEUR</h1>
    <h3>WITHOUT RELOAD THE WHOLE PAGE</h3>
```

If this doesn't work then send simple text response.. hope this will work